# Is there syntactic sugar when declaring generic types?

Tags: java, generics, syntactic-sugar

Suppose I have this class

```
class Generic<T extends List<? extends Integer>, E extends List<? extends Integer>>
```

or any long generic type inside the diamond brackets. When working with this class, in order to keep type safety, I need to keep mentioning the generic type. So, for example, if I want to iterate over a `Set` of the above class or manipulate it, I need to do the following:

```
class SomeClass {

    <T extends List<? extends Integer>, E extends List<? extends Integer>> void add(Set<Generic<T, E>> mySet, Generic<T, E> toAdd) {

        mySet.add(toAdd);
    }

    <T extends List<? extends Integer>, E extends List<? extends Integer>> void iterate(Set<Generic<T, E>> mySet) {

        for (Generic<T, E> myGeneric : mySet)
        {
                // do something with myGeneric
        }
    }
}
```

However, this becomes very cumbersome very quickly. I searched and could not find some sort of way to deal with this properly. I know that one can write `Generic<?, ?>` but this hinders type safety checks as much as I know.

Is there a way to deal with this properly? Some way to name `T extends List<? extends Integer>, E extends List<? extends Integer` and use that name just as a syntax shortcut maybe?

**Quick note:** I am not talking about the *initialization* syntactic sugar introduced in Java 7 where the right hand side can have empty diamond brackets using type inference from the *declaration*.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, but I think you're not working correctly with your type-parameters.

When your method is generic, then you can easily *refer* to the method's type-parameters without having to rewrite their bounds every time:

```
<T extends List<? extends Integer>, E extends List<? extends Integer>> 
void iterate(Set<Generic<T, E>> mySet) {
    for (Generic<T, E> myGeneric : mySet) {
        // do something with myGeneric
    }
}
```

This is also valid if you class is Generic, i.e. something like:

```
class SomeClass<T extends List<? extends Integer>, E extends List<? extends Integer>> {
   void iterate(Set<Generic<T, E>> mySet) {
        for (Generic<T, E> myGeneric : mySet) {
            // do something with myGeneric
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, declaring the generic type in the method or class is something I knew about already (+1 anyway), but is still annoying. I was thinking If there is a way to "name" all the contents of the `<...>` and reuse that "name" everywhere else. Also, why do you think I'm not working correctly with the type parameters?

Comment: Oops! When I simplified the question I lost the right code. Please see my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can use

```
mySet.forEach(myGeneric -> {
    ...
});
```

So you don't need to specify the `myGeneric` type at all, it will be inferred. There are some known limitations with such approach though (like inability to modify local variables of outer method or inability to throw the checked exceptions).

Comment: Yes, nice, but that only solves the example of iteration clutter, right?

Comment: @user1803551, yes, in normal method declaration you still need to specify the full signature.